# Customizing my Own model in Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, crf

Could I ask about Stanford NER?? Actually, I'm trying to train my own model, to use it later for learning. According to the documentation, I have to add my own features in SeqClassifierFlags and add code for each Feature in NERFeatureFactory.

My questions is that, I have my tokens with all features extracted and Last column represents the label. So, is there any way in Stanford NER to give it my Tab-Delimeted file which contains 30 columns (1 is word , 28 are featurs, and 1 is label) to train my own model without spending time for extracting features??? 
Of course, in Testing phase, I will give it a file like the the aforementioned file without label to predict the label.

Is this possible or Not??

Many thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [FAQ page](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml), the only way to customize the NER model is by inserting the data and specifying the features that you want to extract.

But, wait ... you have the data, and you have managed to extract the features,  so I think you don't need the NER model, you need a classifier. I know this answer is pretty pretty late, but maybe this [classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier) will be a good place to start.